# row to column using awk

Tags: unix, awk

I would like to know how I could transform the following ('Old') to 'New1' and 'New2' using awk:

Old:

```
5
21
31
4
5
11
12
15
5
19
5
12
5
.
.
```

New1:

```
5 21 31 4
5 11 12 15
5 19
5 12
. 
.
```

New2:

```
521314
5111215
519
512
. 
.
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Requires gawk for multi-character `RS`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n5\n"} {$1=$1; print (NR>1 ? 5 OFS $0 : $0)}' file
5 21 31 4
5 11 12 15
5 19
5 12
```

For the second version, just set `OFS` to the empty string:

```
$ awk -v OFS="" 'BEGIN {RS="\n5\n"} {$1=$1; print (NR>1 ? 5 OFS $0 : $0)}' file
521314
5111215
519
512
```

Comment: `print (NR>1 ? 5 OFS $0 : $0)` will work better, so you can have the same code for both by setting `OFS=" "` or to `""`

Comment: Genius, as always, @karakfa. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

To get `new1`:

```
awk '/^5/{printf "%s", (NR>1?RS:"")$0;next}{printf " %s",$0}END{print ""}' file
```

To get `new2`:

```
awk '/^5/{printf "%s", (NR>1?RS:"")$0;next}{printf "%s",$0}END{print ""}' file
```

Comment: you may want to add the `$` right bound as well, otherwise `51` will trigger a new record (not sure the domain allows it though)

Comment: @karakfa you are right about `$` and 51. I don't know what is the exact requirement. the line beginning with `5` or exact `5`

Answer (score 1):

some variation of @jas's script

```
$ awk -v RS="(^|\n)5\n" -v OFS='' 'NR>1{$1=$1; print 5,$0}' file
521314
5111215
519
512

$ awk -v RS="(^|\n)5\n" -v OFS=' ' 'NR>1{$1=$1; print 5,$0}' file
5 21 31 4
5 11 12 15
5 19
5 12
```

in the second one you don't have to set the `OFS` explicitly since it's the default value, otherwise both scripts are the same (essentially same as the other referenced answer).

Comment: This also improves on the referenced answer by using a regexp for `RS` and then ignoring the first (empty) record, making for a cleaner action body.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '{print ($0==5 ? ors : OFS) $0; ors=RS} END{print ors}' file
5 21 31 4
5 11 12 15
5 19
5 12

$ awk -v ORS= -v OFS= '{print ($0==5 ? ors : OFS) $0; ors=RS} END{print ors}' file
521314
5111215
519
512
```